# C# store file lines into array, then save chosen lines

Tags: c#, arrays, file

I am trying to make code, that will basically open desired file, store all lines into array, and then, if line does fulfill condition, line will be save into new text file. When running program, I get error message to line reader, that index is outside of array. Please help, I am new to C#

```
 int NumLines = new StreamReader(OpenFile.FileName).ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' }).Length;
            StreamReader Data = new StreamReader(OpenFile.FileName);
            string[] arr = new string[NumLines];
            for (int i = 0; i <= NumLines; i++)
            {
                StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter("C://Users//Tomas//Desktop//BC//tmp//Data.txt");
                arr[i] = Data.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You probably do not read the same file twice... but why should you read the file twice by the way ? :)

Comment: Once i wanted to find number of lines and then read them to find specific lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index should be less than array size:

```
for (int i = 0; i < NumLines; i++)
                  ^
```

But you don't need to put lines into array in order to write them to other file. E.g. if you want to write only some lines by condition:

```
File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, File.ReadLines(OpenFile.FileName).Where(condition));
```

Where *condition* is a delegate which checks whether line should be written. E.g. if you want to write only lines which start with `"Foo"`:

```
.Where(line => line.StartsWith("Foo"))
```

NOTE: If you want to write all lines to new file without condition, then you simply can *copy* original file:

```
File.Copy(OpenFile.FileName, newFileName);
```

---

UPDATE: From your comments, it's clear that you need to find line which matches some condition and also write to output 6th and 8th lines after that line. You still can do that without dumping all source file into memory:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetVertexCoordinates(string fileName)
{
    var enumerator = File.ReadLines(fileName).GetEnumerator();

    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        if (enumerator.Current == "VERTEX")
        {
            yield return enumerator.Current;

            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) enumerator.MoveNext(); // skip 6 lines
            yield return enumerator.Current; 

            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) enumerator.MoveNext(); // skip 2 more lines
            yield return enumerator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

And usage is still one-liner

```
File.WriteAllLines(newFileName, GetVertexCoordinates(OpenFile.FileName));
```

Comment: @TomasMichalek so.. you want to find line "VERTEX" in source file and then write three lines in output: "VERTES" and two lines with +6 and +8 indexes from source file?

Comment: Thank you. But I want it in array because I want t find specific line and write some lines under.

Example of condition:

``if (arr[i] == "VERTEX")
                    {
                        File.WriteLine("VERTEX");
                        File.WriteLine(arr[i + 6]);
                        File.WriteLine(arr[i + 8]);
                    }

Comment: @TomasMichalek can you answer to my question? It's like yes or no :) And some comments if 'no'

Comment: Yes, i want that, sorry, but my internet falls and i keep rewriting post... its stormy outside. waht I am doing is, that I want to rewrite DXF file (for CAD/CAM) into coordinates, so if file finds for example line VERTEX, it will write line vertex and coordinates, which are 6 and 8 lines under

Comment: So no everything works, i had logical error in code. Thanks to you I have overcome that index error. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @TomasMichalek I have added sample which matches your condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(filepath);
```

Then, if you need to compare all lines of this file with some YOUR line, you can do this way:

```
string targetFilePath = "C://Users//Tomas//Desktop//BC//tmp//Data.txt";
string specificLine = "line, which you try to find";
foreach (var line in lines)
    if (line.Equals(specificLine))
        File.WriteAllText(targetFilePath, line);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could be shortcutted this way...

```
   /// Disposal of your reader when unused is essential to close your file
   using(var reader = new StreamReader(OpenFile.FileName))   
   {
      var lines = reader.ReadToEnd().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
      int NumLines = lines.Length;
      for (int i = 0; i < NumLines; i++)
      {
           ... do something here
      }
   }
```